# How to train an RL agent in a custom environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have created a custom space, which extends the OpenAI gym.Space. I need this space because I need an action space that sums up to a value. Using this, I can scale up the output and meet my requirement.

```py
class ProbabilityBox(Space):
    """
        Values add up to 1 and each value lies between 0 and 1
    """
    def __init__(self, size=None):
        assert isinstance(size, int) and size > 0
        self.size = size
        gym.Space.__init__(self, (), np.int64)

    def sample(self):
        return np.around(np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(self.size), size=1), decimals=2)[0]

    def contains(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
            if np.sum(x) != 1:
                return False
            
            for i in x:
                if i > 1 or i < 0:
                    return False
            
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ProbabilityBox({self.size})"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.size == other.size
```

I am using this space in an action space in a custom environment. I am unable to train this agent in `stable-baselines3` because it does not support custom spaces.

1. Is there an alternate way to model this scenario so that I can work with `stable-baselines3`?
2. What other libraries/frameworks can I use to train an RL agent that supports custom spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Stable baselines does support custom envs. See [docs](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_env.html).

Answer (score 0):

stable-baselines 3 does not support action spaces different from `Dicrete / MultiDiscrete / Box` and there is absolutely no need in custom action spaces, because your action(s) is (are) fully determined by an output of your neural network being consequently either a natural/real number or a vector of them, so that three above mentioned classes fully cover them